# Can this Luks partition be accessed/mounted?

Tags: dual-boot, encryption

I shutdown my computer tonight with the intention of restarting it and I couldn't get it to reboot. I got an Initramfs screen instead. I have a dual boot with XP and Ubuntu (/boot is on a thumb drive). I booted with a live DVD to see if I could access the Luks encrypted partition. I was able to unlock the partition but not mount it. I got the following messages, one from attempting to mount it and one from running the terminal command that was suggested.

```
Error mounting /dev/dm-0 at /media/ubuntu/e5b09176-f97c-4d07-8dcd-9cdb957c144c: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/dm-0" "/media/ubuntu/e5b09176-f97c-4d07-8dcd-9cdb957c144c"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/luks-66410953-f09b-4435-8904-0d0957e4aadb,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail
```

or so

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg|tail
[  453.592648]         1b 80 68 37
[  453.592657] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 
[  453.592663] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[  453.592669] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  453.592673] Read(10): 28 00 1b 80 67 68 00 00 f0 00
[  453.592691] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 461400119
[  453.592722] ata3: EH complete
[  453.598066] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 1286
[  453.598252] JBD2: recovery failed
[  453.598260] EXT4-fs (dm-0): error loading journal
```

Comment: try to `e2fsck` to repair the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks. That did it. I just used fsck from a live DVD though. It's my understanding that the command will recognize the fs type and proceed accordingly.